# No implementation for play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider was bound

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I can't get slick to work with play 2.5.x

I get the following runtime error:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
```

My DAO looks like:

```
@Singleton
class UserDAO @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) 
extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
    import driver.api._

...

}
```

And I just inject it in my controller like:

```
@Singleton
class UserController @Inject() (ws: WSClient, cache: CacheApi, userDAO: UserDAO) extends Controller {
...
}
```

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
  // database
  jdbc,
  "org.postgresql"     %  "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0"
)
```

My application.conf has:

```
play.db {
  # The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  #config = "db"
  #default = "default"

  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
    #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
  }
}

## JDBC Datasource
db {
  default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
  default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb_development"
  default.username = "blankman"
  #default.password = ""
}
```

If I change my database name I get a connection error, so the pool is picking up my config settings correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue I can see with your application.conf is that it misses the play-slick specific configuration keys. In fact, you should remove the *db* section from your application.conf, and replace it with *slick.dbs* as shown in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick#database-configuration

Another thing you likely want to do is removing the *jdbc* dependency from your sbt build file, as to my knowledge (which is based on Play 2.4.x) you can't use both play-slick and jdbc on the same Play project.

I'd definitely suggest you to read the Play-Slick documentation to better understand how it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This needs to be outside the `db { }`

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem with this config in application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/[db_name]"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=[name_db]
slick.dbs.default.db.password=[pw_bd]
```

Please note to change database name to something else other than default. Only change db_name.

Comment: This needs to be outside the `db { }`