# Play 2.5.12 getting error ProvisionException: Unable to provision No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound

Tags: java, playframework, typesafe-config

I have upgraded all my `play.Configuration` code to the `com.typesafe.config.Config` classes.  I am running an application using Play Framework 2.5.12.

I am now using:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
...
    @Inject
    static Config config;
```

I can `clean` and `compile` the code, but when I `run` the application, I receive this error:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound.
  while locating com.typesafe.config.Config
    for field at controllers.IntakeController.config(IntakeController.java:66)
  while locating controllers.IntakeController
    for parameter 3 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:80)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

2) No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound.
  while locating com.typesafe.config.Config
    for field at controllers.account.Reset.config(Reset.java:43)
  while locating controllers.account.Reset
    for parameter 7 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:80)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

3) No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound.
  while locating com.typesafe.config.Config
    for field at controllers.account.Signup.config(Signup.java:50)
  while locating controllers.account.Signup
    for parameter 6 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:80)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

3 errors
```

With the rest of the error stating:

```
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound.
  while locating com.typesafe.config.Config
    for field at controllers.IntakeController.config(IntakeController.java:66)
  while locating controllers.IntakeController
    for parameter 3 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:80)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

2) No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound.
  while locating com.typesafe.config.Config
    for field at controllers.account.Reset.config(Reset.java:43)
  while locating controllers.account.Reset
    for parameter 7 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:80)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

3) No implementation for com.typesafe.config.Config was bound.
  while locating com.typesafe.config.Config
    for field at controllers.account.Signup.config(Signup.java:50)
  while locating controllers.account.Signup
    for parameter 6 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:80)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

3 errors
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

I found a couple of posts:

[No implementation for play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider was bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338904/no-implementation-for-play-api-db-slick-databaseconfigprovider-was-bound)

[Play error on startup: No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825728/play-error-on-startup-no-implementation-for-play-api-db-database-was-bound)

but they did not help me out.

I did find one post where the solution was to add this:

```
play.modules.enabled += com.typesafe.config.Config
```

to the `application.conf` file.  I had a feeling it would not work and it did not.

Any help would be great.

--------------------------- EDIT 4/5/18 ----------------------------

I added a module and provider to the code:
Module:

```
package module;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;

public class ConfigModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Config.class).toProvider(providers.ConfigProvider.class);
  }
}
```

Provider:

```
package providers;

import com.typesafe.config.Config;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ConfigProvider implements Provider<Config> {

  private final Config configuration;

  @Inject
  public ConfigProvider(Config configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
  }

  @Override
  public Config get() {
    return this.configuration.getConfig("application.conf");
  }

}
```

I also added:

```
playmodules.enabled += "modules.ConfigModule"
```

to the `application.conf` file.

After this, I still get the same error.

Comment: Why would you not use `play.Configuration`?

Comment: From 2.5.18, I am moving to 2.6.x and it is deprecated is 2.6.x.

Comment: That should not be an issue. I use Play 2.6, and still using `play.api.Configuration` maybe the package has changed?!
Here is the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaConfig

Comment: You can try: `ConfigFactory.load()` instead of `this.configuration.getConfig("application.conf")` and removing all @Inject with `Config`  - or better create a new Play project to verify if you hit a bug or that you can compare your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an implementation for `com.typesafe.config.Config` as this only an interface.

As this is done by `ConfigFactory` you have to use that with a [Factory Provider](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryProvider.html) (Guice)

Personally I just create the Config statically with the Factory:

```
 def config(): Config = {
    ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()
    ConfigFactory.load()
  }
```

See here the whole class: [AdaptersContext.scala](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters/blob/master/server/app/pme123/adapters/server/entity/AdaptersContext.scala)

Comment: Do you an example of how to do this in Play?  These help me out more if I see the code itself.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: I never have done that -  I adjusted my answer so you get another possibility.

Comment: I am using Java.  I used this document -- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaConfigMigration26

Comment: Have you also tried exactly as it is described?

`public class Foo {
    private final Config config;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    public Foo(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}`

Comment: I added a module and provider - I updated my original post with what I added, but still receiving the error.

Comment: the version in my former comment you tried as well?
(`public class Foo { private final Config config; @javax.inject.Inject public Foo(Config config) { this.config = config; } }`)

Comment: Yes.  I added `private final Config config;@Inject public Reset(Config config) {this.config = config;}` to the controllers (IntakeController, Reset, and Signup) and still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in migrating from Play 2.3 to Play 2.4 (my goal is to move it to 2.7 incrementally), and the new `play-mailer` started to complain about the same issue.

**The Fix**

1. Create a module like below, you might already have such
2. Add @provides that will provide the Conf object.

   ```
   package modules;

   import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
   import com.google.inject.Provides;
   import com.typesafe.config.Config;
   import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

   public class JavaModules extends AbstractModule {

       @Override
       protected void configure() {

       }

       @Provides
       public Config ProvideConfigFactory() {
           return ConfigFactory.load("application.conf");
       }
   }
   ```

**Hook Up The Module in the application.conf **

(If your issue is not due to the Mailer Module, please omit that line).

```
play.modules {
        enabled += "modules.JavaModules"
        enabled += "play.api.libs.mailer.MailerModule"
    }
```